# Pressing Enter button in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Pressing enter in puppeteer doesn't seem to have any effect. However, when I press other keys, it does what it should. 
This works:

```
await page.press('ArrowLeft');
```

This doesn't:

```
await page.press('Enter');
```

This is how the input looks like:

[image]

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've also tried page.keyboard.down & page.keyboard.up to be sure.

Comment: Perhaps try [`'Accept'`](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#keys-ui)?

Comment: I've tried `await page.press('Accept')` but no result :(

Comment: Follow this link  [keys-special](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#keys-special), and maybe, it is not page.press('Enter') not works, maybe you catch page just listen to mouseup event.

Comment: did u try `await page.press('Return')`

Comment: @Carson What do you mean? I looked at that page before.

Comment: Return doesn't seem to have an effect either. I will upload an image of how the input looks like.

Comment: enter is not Navigation Keys, maybe depend on your OS or others, you can try with that page

Comment: @elena did u try any other methods? link [keyboarddownkey](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboarddownkey-options)

Comment: @Carson press is a shortcut for keyboarddown + keyboardup

Comment: puppeteer sample says: ` page.press('native key') // like ArrowLeft`  `page.keyboard.up('special key') // like Shift`

Comment: I see, like a click. but when pages only listen keyup, does press works well

Comment: I've tested, page.press("Enter") works well

Comment: It doesn't work in my case though :(

Comment: I've told u, It is works for you, but not expected for you. your question is screenshot after `page.press("Enter")` but before "Enter" event trigger something complete.

Comment: maybe you can post more code to desc yours questions

Comment: I am also having this problem. I am running puppeteer with `puppeteer.launch({headless: false});` so I can see what's going on, and ArrowLeft works, but Enter doesn't.
I checked the API documentation, and it clearly says that `page.press("Enter")` is the way to do this, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

Using [this site](http://w3c.github.io/uievents/tools/key-event-viewer) I noticed that `page.type` dispatches `beforeinput` and `input` events, but `page.press` doesn't. This is probably a bug, but fortunately sending the enter keycode (13) seems to work, so we can work around it for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BlackCap, it works indeed! Very smart!

Comment: I had to use `page.keyboard.press(String.fromCharCode(13));`

Answer (score 99):

I've used `page.keyboard.press('Enter');` usually :) Works for me.

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#keyboardpresskey-options). I think you should use `.keyboard` before `.press` for it to work properly.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: Not sure what to elaborate. I think you should add `.keyboard` before `.press` for it to work. At least this is how I simulate pressing Enter in my applications.

Comment: @Sid [The answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606115/6243352), which was added a year after your comment, has all the elaboration you'd probably want....

Answer (score 64):

#### page.keyboard.press():

You can use [`page.keyboard.press()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardpresskey-options) to simulate pressing the enter key. Any of the following options should work:

```
await page.keyboard.press('Enter'); // Enter Key
await page.keyboard.press('NumpadEnter'); // Numeric Keypad Enter Key
await page.keyboard.press('\n'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.press('\r'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
```

#### elementHandle.press():

Additionally, you can use use a combination of [`page.$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector) and [`elementHandle.press()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlepresskey-options) to focus on an element before pressing enter:

```
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('Enter'); // Enter Key
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('NumpadEnter'); // Numeric Keypad Enter Key
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('\n'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
await (await page.$('input[type="text"]')).press('\r'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
```

#### page.type():

Furthermore, you can use [`page.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagetypeselector-text-options):

```
await page.type(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

#### page.keyboard.type():

Likewise, you can use [`page.keyboard.type()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardtypetext-options):

```
await page.keyboard.type(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

#### page.keyboard.sendCharacter():

Another alternative method would be to use the [`page.keyboard.sendCharacter()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardsendcharacterchar) method:

```
await page.keyboard.sendCharacter(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

#### page.keyboard.down() / page.keyboard.up():

You can also use a combination of [`page.keyboard.down()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboarddownkey-options) and [`page.keyboard.up()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#keyboardupkey):

```
// Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('Enter');
await page.keyboard.up('Enter');

// Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('NumpadEnter');
await page.keyboard.up('NumpadEnter');

// Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('\n');
await page.keyboard.up('\n');

// Shortcut for Enter Key
await page.keyboard.down('\r');
await page.keyboard.up('\r');
```

Comment: the normal `page.keyboard.press('Enter')` doesn't work in my case, but `await (await page.$(selector).press('Enter');` WORKS.

Answer (score 11):

`await page.keyboard.press('Enter');` This work for me

Comment: This works. Make sure your page is fully  loaded first.

Answer (score 6):

short answer it might be a good idea to attach to the input control first :

```
    await page.type('#inp_srch_box', 'add');
    await page.type('#inp_srch_box',String.fromCharCode(13));
```

Long answer ...

```
  cat package.json
  {
    "name": "test-open-login",
    "version": "0.7.9",
    "description": "an example test to test the login of the qto app",
    "main": "test-open-login.test.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "mocha --recursive test",
      "server": "http-server src"
    },
    "license": "BSD",
    "devDependencies": {
      "mocha": "5.0.1",
      "puppeteer": "^2.1.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "chai": "^4.2.0",
      "http-server": "^0.12.1",
      "mocha": "5.0.1"
    }
  }

  cat test/test-login.spec.js

  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  async function main(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720})
    await page.goto('https://qto.fi/qto/login', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); 
  // wait until
  await page.type('#email', 'test.anonymous.user@gmail.com');
  //await page.type('#pass', 'secret');
  // click and wait for navigation


  await page.waitFor(1000);
  //await frame.waitFor(1000);
  await Promise.all([
     page.click('#butLogin'),
     page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
  ]);

    await page.type('#inp_srch_box', 'add');
    await page.type('#inp_srch_box',String.fromCharCode(13));
  }

  main();
```

Answer (score 4):

Its **page.keyboard.press()**

Reference: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v3.0.0&show=api-keyboardpresskey-options

Find keynames and keycodes at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/src/USKeyboardLayout.js

Answer (score 1):

I have used `await page.keyboard.press('Enter');` in my code and it worked perfectly fine for me.