# Puppeteer Press Enter Button or Click Dialog OK Button

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

[OK button dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSejS.gif)

I'm at the end of a Puppeteer script. I just need to click the OK button on the confirm dialog box (see link to image) or press the enter key. For pressing the enter key I tried every suggestion here [Pressing Enter button in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442253/pressing-enter-button-in-puppeteer) and nothing worked. I checked with a normal browser and pressing the enter key works. Any suggestions?

Problem solved thanks to Thomas! See solution below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a confirm dialog. Have a look at [dialog handling](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.7.0/docs/api.md#class-dialog).

You can press the OK button like this:

```js
page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
    await dialog.accept();
});
```

Put the code in front of the action that triggers the dialog (otherwise the event handler will not be registered when the dialog event is fired).

Answer (score 0):

Note that another way that I used on puppeteer sharp is to duckpunch (redefine) the alert dialog as follows:

```
Log(robot, "js duckpunch alert dialog ");
var jsExec = @"
function alert(msg) {  
   console.log('dialog: '+msg)
}
";
await ExecJsExpression(page, jsExec, settings.robot);
Log(robot, "js duckpunch alert dialog done ");
```

...

where Log is an audit log function of some sort. The variable robot can be ignored, it's just holding state in my example.

...

and ExecJsExpression is as follows:

```
private static async Task ExecJsExpression(Page page, string jsExec, RobotState robot) {
    Log(robot, "js exec [" + jsExec + "]");


    Log(robot, "js exec cleaned [" + jsExec + "]");
    try {
        await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync(jsExec);
        Log(robot, "js exec [" + jsExec + "] ok");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log(robot, "Failed to exec js expr [" + jsExec + "]");
        throw;
    }
}
```