# puppeteer press Enter on input type search

Tags: keyboard, puppeteer, enter

I want to press key enter, after fill a input, but nothing happens, it is not a link or button to click

```
<div class="search-input">
    <a class="search machin" style="display:none;z-index: 0;position: absolute;"></a>
    <input type="search" id="global-search"> //events jquery keypress and keyup
    <a class="close-search" style="z-index: 0;">
       <i class="m times"></i>
    </a>
</div>
jquery : function(t) {
  return "undefined" != typeof w && w.event.triggered !== t.type ? w.event.dispatch.apply(e, 
arguments) : void 0
}
```

I verify with screenshot that the input type="search" was well filled and it is.

```
await page.focus('#global-search');
await page.type('#global-search',"string to find"); //it works
```

or  `await page.$eval('#global-search', (el, value) => el.value = value, myLocalValue);//it works`

i try this:
    `await page.keyboard.press("Enter");`
or
    `await page.keyboard.down('Enter');`
    `await page.keyboard.up('Enter');`

**the press button Enter have to complete the url** https://lesite.fr/recherche?q=string_to_find but it is not the case the url remains desperately https://lesite.fr/

I must find the result of the seach in

```
<div class="h-container">
    <div class="h">
        <div class="h-image SearchBanner">
            <img src="/-/media/_banner.jpg">
            <div class="rot-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="h-details">
            <h1>16 RÉSULTATS</h1>
            <div class="search-result">HERE THE RESULT<span class="secondary-title">string to find</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the probleme is the url is not completed

i read a lot of google search ([Pressing Enter button in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442253/pressing-enter-button-in-puppeteer..).)

Help

Comment: puppeteer "version": "24.8.0"

Comment: I think press enter works but not on the right place because it works fine on a other link

Answer (score 4):

```
        await page.focus('#header > div.component.container.float-wrapper > div.search > div > div.search-input');
         await page.type('#header > div.component.container.float-wrapper > div.search > div > div.search-input',"PSG");
        await page.keyboard.press('ArrowRight');
        await page.focus('#header > div.component.container.float-wrapper > div.search > div > div.search-input');
        await page.keyboard.press('Enter'); // Enter Key
        await page.keyboard.press('NumpadEnter'); // Numeric Keypad Enter Key
        await page.keyboard.press('\n'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
        await page.keyboard.press('\r'); // Shortcut for Enter Key
```

it works after 30 hours to search

Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In this working example, it will search Google from an HTML input search tag.

Try this workaround, and tell me if this solve your problem.
Try also each commented 4 lines above it.

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer')

;(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch ({
        headless: false,
        devtools: true,
        slowMo: 50 // delete this if you like
    })
    const contentHTML = '<form name="search" method="get" action="https://www.google.com/search?"><div class="search-input"><a class="search machin" style="display:none;z-index: 0;position: absolute;"></a><input type="search" id="global-search" name="q"><a class="close-search" style="z-index: 0;"><i class="m times"></i></a></div></form>'
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0]
    // const google = await page.goto('https://www.google.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    const setContent = await page.setContent(contentHTML, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'})

    const focusSearch = await page.focus('#global-search')
    const typeSearch = await page.type('#global-search',"string_to_find") //it works

    const searchSubmitted = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'}),

        // const pressReturn = page.type('#global-search', '\r'),
        // const pressReturn = page.type('#global-search', String.fromCharCode(13)),
        // const pressReturn = page.keyboard.type('\n'),
        // const pressReturn = page.keyboard.down('NumpadEnter'),
        const pressReturn = page.keyboard.press('Enter') // 4 LINES ABOVE ALSO WORKS, TRY THEM ALL
    ])

    // 'Enter': {'keyCode': 13, 'code': 'Enter', 'key': 'Enter', 'text': '\r'}

    // <div class="search-result">HERE THE RESULT<span class="secondary-title">string to find</span></div>

    // const searchString = await page.$eval('span.secondary-title', el => el.innerText);


})()
```

Comment: Sorry for my answer slow

Comment: my answer is before your answer