# How to select a search bar without a `name`?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, puppeteer

I would like to perform a search in the below search bar using Puppeteer. However I can't see anything I can use to identify the search bar by.

If I do:

```
await page.type('[id="i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb"]', 'test="1 2" and test2="3 4"');
await page.type('["data-test-subj"="queryInput"]', 'test="1 2" and test2="3 4"');
await page.type('[class=".euiTextArea.euiTextArea--resizeVertical.euiTextArea--fullWidth.kbnQueryBar__textarea.kbnQueryBar__textarea--hasPrepend.kbnQueryBar__textarea--hasAppend"]', 'test="1 2" and test2="3 4"');
await page.type("*[role='search']", 'test="1 2" and test2="3 4"');
```

then the first 3 give:

```
Error: No node found for selector:
```

and the last one doesn't give any errors.

If I do:

```
await page.waitForSelector('i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb');
await page.focus('i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb');
await page.focus('i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb', '1234', {delay: 1500});
```

I get:

```
TimeoutError: waiting for selector `i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

What can I use to fill in text in the search bar?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try running through the elements if they have the same nested layout every time? `div > div[class=foo] > div > textarea`

Comment: There's a specific `data-test-` attribute right on the element, is there a reason you're not using that? You could also select it by the placeholder or label attributes, which more closely reflects how an end user would find it.

Comment: None of your first three attempts should be capable of throwing the error `Error: No node found for selector: *[id='#i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb']`. Can you ensure that this error text is accurate to what is thrown in actuality...?

Comment: `page.waitForSelector('i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb');` Did you mean to prepend this with a `#` token to indicate that you're waiting for an ID of this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with your second methodology, you need to use the correct CSS selector by prepending a `#` to indicate the value `i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb` is an `id` value, *and* to switch the last line to call `page.type()` instead of `page.focus()` (which doesn't take more than one argument nor implements any sort of typing functionality):

```
await page.waitForSelector('#i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb');
await page.focus('#i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb');
await page.type('#i0e792821-542f-11ec-9366-f3e8261f9ecb', '1234', {delay: 1500});
```

However with selectors that aren't super human-readable, you should generally assume that they are dynamically generated somewhere at build or run-time and will change over time - every time it changes your script will break and you'll have to re-work your code to update the selector. Instead, use a selector that's a bit more human-readable and thus more likely to remain constant:

```
await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-subj="queryInput"]');
await page.focus('[data-test-subj="queryInput"]');
await page.type('[data-test-subj="queryInput"]', '1234', {delay: 1500});
```

Comment: The first didn't work, but your second did =) Thanks =)

Comment: Yuo wouldn't happen to know how it can press Enter? There are no submit button...

Comment: @SandraSchlichting A simple Google query can get you to the resource you need (on this very site in fact!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46442253/pressing-enter-button-in-puppeteer

Comment: Ups. Sorry. Thanks a lot again! I have spend 3-4 hours on this...

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know Puppeteer (or the syntax), but I would imagine something like; `div[role="search"].textarea` or `div[role="search"] > textarea`